# Why doesn't copy elision work in my static functional implementation?

Tags: c++, c++17, type-erasure

I am trying to implement a "static" sized function, that uses preallocated store, unlike `std::function` that uses dynamic heap allocations.

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, size_t StackSize = 64>
class static_function;

// TODO: move and swap
//  - can move smaller instance to larger instance
//  - only instances of the same size are swappable
// TODO: condiotnal dynamic storage?
template <typename Ret, typename ... Args, size_t StackSize>
class static_function<Ret(Args...), StackSize>
{
public:
    constexpr static size_t static_size = StackSize;
    using return_type = Ret;

    template <typename Callable>
    constexpr explicit static_function(Callable &&callable)
        : pVTable_(std::addressof(v_table::template get<Callable>()))
    {
        static_assert(sizeof(std::decay_t<Callable>) <= static_size, "Callable type is too big!");

        new (&data_) std::decay_t<Callable>(std::forward<Callable>(callable));
    }

    constexpr return_type operator()(Args ... args) const
    {
        return (*pVTable_)(data_, std::move(args)...);
    }

    ~static_function() noexcept
    {
        pVTable_->destroy(data_);
    }

private:
    using stack_data = std::aligned_storage_t<static_size>;

    struct v_table
    {
        virtual return_type operator()(const stack_data&, Args &&...) const = 0;
        virtual void destroy(const stack_data&) const = 0;

        template <typename Callable>
        static const v_table& get()
        {
            struct : v_table {
                return_type operator()(const stack_data &data, Args &&... args) const override 
                {
                    return (*reinterpret_cast<const Callable*>(&data))(std::move(args)...);
                }

                void destroy(const stack_data &data) const override
                {
                    reinterpret_cast<const Callable*>(&data)->~Callable();
                }

            } constexpr static vTable_{};

            return vTable_;
        }  
    };    

private:
    stack_data data_;
    const v_table *pVTable_;
};
```

However, it does not work as expected, since copies of the `callable` (copy elision does not kick in like in just lambda).
Here is what is expected vs actiual behavior with `-O3`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    struct prisoner 
    {
        std::string name;

        ~prisoner()
        {
            if (!name.empty())
                std::cout << name << " has been executed\n";
        }
    };

    std::cout << "Expected:\n";
    {
        const auto &func = [captured = prisoner{"Pvt Ryan"}](int a, int b) -> std::string {
            std::cout << captured.name << " has been captured!\n";
            return std::string() + "oceanic " + std::to_string(a + b);
        };
        std::cout << func(4, 811) << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << "THE END\n\n";

    std::cout << "Actual:\n";
    {
        const auto &func = static_function<std::string(int, int)>([captured = prisoner{"Pvt Ryan"}](int a, int b) -> std::string {
            std::cout << captured.name << " has been captured!\n";
            return std::string() + "oceanic " + std::to_string(a + b);
        });

        std::cout << func(4, 811) << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << "THE END!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Expected:
Pvt Ryan has been captured!
oceanic 815
Pvt Ryan has been executed
THE END

Actual:
Pvt Ryan has been executed
Pvt Ryan has been captured!
oceanic 815
Pvt Ryan has been executed
THE END!
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zc3d1Eave

**What did I do wrong within the implementation?**

Comment: @SamVarshavchik what problem does your question intend to solve?

Comment: Sam is referring to this: https://xyproblem.info.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know. Virtually **every** problem is an *xy* problem. So unless this question has **particular** problems regarding meeting SO requirements, I don't feel anyone is obliged to admit anything about "x" or "y". "x" might be some corporate task that can't be discussed here. Or it may be just curiosity. So his comment is very irrelevant and quite counterproductive.

Comment: The specific problem was that the question was about a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik so now I renamed the question asking about a particular problem. I expected copy-elision to kick in like in the first lambda case. But it doesn't. And I lack the knowledge to find out the reason on my own.

Comment: There's one instance of copy elision in the first part (initializing `captured`), which still works fine in the second part. The additional destructor in the second part comes from the lambda itself being destroyed after it was moved from to construct the `static_function`. In the first part the lambda is simply lifetime-extended by the const reference. I'm not sure you can copy-elide into a member with the rest of the initialization that `static_function` requires.

Comment: @Quentin I suppose that if `static_function` stored the exact type of the lambda it was initialized with, copy elision would work.

Comment: Are you building as release? debug builds (at least on msvc version I used) do not have to do it

Comment: @PepijnKramer I explicitly mentioned that I had `-O3` optimization. And there's also a link to godbolt

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Me bad ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to elide the copy/move. The capture is constructed when the lambda expression is evaluated in the caller resulting in a temporary object. That lambda is then passed to the constructor and the constructor explicitly constructs a new object of that type in the storage by copy/move from the passed lambda. You can't identify the object created by placement-new with the temporary object passed to the constructor.

The only way to resolve such an issue is by not constructing the lambda with the capture that should not be copied/moved in the caller at all, but to instead pass a generator for the lambda which is then evaluated by the constructor when constructing the new object with placement-new. Something like:

```
template <typename CallableGenerator, typename... Args>
constexpr explicit static_function(CallableGenerator&& generator, Args&&... args)
    : pVTable_(std::addressof(v_table::template get<std::invoke_result_t<CallableGenerator, Args...>>()))
{
    static_assert(sizeof(std::decay_t<std::invoke_result_t<CallableGenerator, Args...>>) <= static_size, "Callable type is too big!");

    new (&data_) auto(std::invoke(std::forward<CallableGenerator>(generator), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

//...

const auto &func = static_function<std::string(int, int)>([](auto str){
    return [captured = prisoner{str}](int a, int b) -> std::string {
        std::cout << captured.name << " has been captured!\n";
        return std::string() + "oceanic " + std::to_string(a + b);
    });
}, "Pvt Ryan");

// or

const auto &func = static_function<std::string(int, int)>([str="Pvt Ryan"]{
    return [captured = prisoner{str}](int a, int b) -> std::string {
        std::cout << captured.name << " has been captured!\n";
        return std::string() + "oceanic " + std::to_string(a + b);
    });
});
```

This requires C++17 or later to guarantee that the copy/move is elided. Before C++17 the elision cannot be guaranteed in this way with a lambda. Instead a manually-defined function object must be used so that its constructor can be passed the arguments like I am doing here with the generator. That would be the equivalent of `emplace`-type functions of standard library types.

Comment: is there maybe a way to "generate" the generator in-private? Like taking the lambda's type and then constructing it. I suppose this will work with stateless lambdas onily though

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Yes, only for capture-less lambdas and also only since C++20. So that is not really helpful.

Comment: `std::construct_at` is `constexpr` and would replace `placement new`, but since C++20, yeah...

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik `std::construct_at` doesn't help you with that. In fact you _can't_ use it in this situation to replace the placement-new. Since it is a function call, the result of the generator call would again be passed to it via its function parameter from which `construct_at` would then construct the object in the storage. This effectively results in exactly the same problem that your original constructor has. It will again force a copy/move.

Comment: you are right. I just tried and got exactly the same result

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik The general issue is that you lose any possibility of copy elision if you pass the object through a function parameter (whether by-value or by-reference). So you need to make sure that you never pass the actual object to a function, but only a proxy that can generate you the object lazily. This is an issue for all functions that intent to store a function argument. They really should all have an overload that accepts a generator instead to make optimal use of C++17 elision guarantees, but because there is no specific language support for lazy evaluation that is too tedious.