# destructor is called twice for variant-based implementation

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, undefined-behavior

I have a variadic `variant_callable` class object that I want to use for a runtime polymorphism. Inside it uses a visitor pattern with `std::variant`.
However, I came by a rather strange behavior, that is object's destructor is called **twice**!.

```
#include <utility>
#include <variant>
#include <tuple>

namespace detail
{
    template<typename... Impl>
    class variadic_callable
    {
    public:
        template<typename T>
        constexpr explicit variadic_callable(T &&t)   //
          : varImpl_(std::forward<T>(t))
        {}

        variadic_callable(const variadic_callable &) = delete;
        variadic_callable(variadic_callable &&) = delete;

        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(Args &&...args) const
        {
            return std::visit(
                [argsTuple = std::forward_as_tuple(args...)](const auto &visitor) {
                    return std::apply(
                        [&visitor](auto &&...args) {
                            return visitor(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
                        },
                        argsTuple);
                },
                varImpl_);
        }

    private:
        std::variant<Impl...> varImpl_;
    };
}   // namespace detail

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char **)
{
    struct callable
    {
        std::string str = "Long enough string to be allocated. Oceanic"; 

        callable()
        {
            std::cout << "callable()" << std::endl;
        }

        void operator()(int i) const
        {
            std::cout << str << " " << i << '\n';
        }

        ~callable()
        {
            std::cout << "~callable()" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    {
        std::cout << "expcected:\n";
        const auto &c = callable();
        c(815);
        std::cout << "finished\n";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    {
        std::cout << "actual\n";
        const auto &w = detail::variadic_callable<callable>{callable()};
        w(815);
        std::cout << "finished\n";
    }

}
```

The output:

```
Program returned: 0
expcected:
callable()
Long enough string to be allocated. Oceanic 815
finished
~callable()

actual
callable()
~callable()
Long enough string to be allocated. Oceanic 815
finished
~callable()
```

https://godbolt.org/z/d849EaqbE

I guess an UB is in-place, but I can't spot it.
What I find the most peculiar is the fact that in the "actual" case `std::string` resources are not destroyed after the first destructor invocation!

Comment: Lets add in a copy constructor and some sanitizers and see what happens: https://godbolt.org/z/rKG5nG95x Looks like  a copy was made somewhere, explaining the extra destructor. Running the program in a debugger and placing a breakpoint in the copy constructor should tell you where and why.

Comment: @user4581301 I assumed that mandatory copy elision would kick in.

Comment: Where, exactly, do you believe that mandatory copy elision happens here?

Comment: I'd expect elision to take place with `callable()` here: `detail::variadic_callable<callable>{callable()}`, but the innards of `variant` get... complicated. Following my own advice, it looks like the copy is happening 10 or 11 function calls into the stuff happening behind the scenes in the constructor call.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik user4581301 has answered your question

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Sam already knew this. He was challenging you to look deeper.

Comment: Mandatory copy elision occurs in very limited circumstances. Which specific use case do you believe applies here? "Perfect forwarding" never involves copy elision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`variadic_callable`'s constructor is being passed an object of type `callable`. This is a temporary object that cannot be the same object as the one stored in the `std::variant` (no matter how it is passed).

The `callable` inside the `std::variant` must therefore be move-constructed from the passed temporary object. Both of these objects need to be eventually destroyed, requiring two calls to `callable`'s destructor.

To prevent this you need to pass the arguments from which `callable` is supposed to be constructed to `variadic_callable`'s constructor instead (here an empty list) and then pass these on to `std::variants` in-place constructor, i.e.

```
 template<typename T, typename... Args>
 constexpr explicit variadic_callable(std::in_place_type_t<T> t, Args&&... args)   //
   : varImpl_(t, std::forward<Args>(args)...)
 {}
```

called as

```
detail::variadic_callable<callable>{std::in_place_type<callable>};
```

Here I copied `std::variant`'s constructor design for the in-place overload.

Comment: Does it mean that elision can not work with perfect forwarding?

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik You can never elide copies through a function call. You can elide copies into the by-value parameter of a function and into the by-value return value. But you can not identify an object in a parameter with the return value or, as here, an object somewhere outside the function with an object inside the function or passed as reference (as here) to the function.

Comment: how would one workaround in_place construction given a factory callable? https://godbolt.org/z/v455echME - the third example

Comment: I just remembered that you answered a similar question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73153603/9363996

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik `std::variant` doesn't offer an interface of the kind I mentioned in my other answer (I don't think any of the standard library does). You'll have to return a full `std::variant` from the lambda. For example: https://godbolt.org/z/n8vW4Yz83. (The second `std::in_place_type` is now redundant, but you still need some tag to distinguish the constructors.) This is probably not a good solution because it requires knowing about an implementation detail of the class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73744465/9363996 I opened a question regarding variant's construction. There's an answer that suggests an approach which seems promising

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Ah ok, I was just about to suggest something similar to that as a more elaborate alternative.

Comment: Your suggestion would be very appreciated :)

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik It would have been equivalent to what the answer in your other question already gives only a bit less elegantly written.