# Is it possible to in-place initailize std::variant given a factory object and variadic arguments list?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, copy-elision

`std::variant` has a constructor that accepts `std::in_place_t<Type>, Args &&...` arguments that results in in-place construction.

```
    {
        std::cout << "in_place_type:\n";
        const auto var = std::variant<callable>(std::in_place_type<callable>);
        std::cout << "finished\n";
    }
```

I wonder if it is somehow possible to in-place construct given a Factory object:

```
    {
        std::cout << "by factory:\n";
        const auto var = std::variant<callable>{[] ()-> callable {return {}; }()};
        std::cout << "finished\n";
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rY5WG1hGn

```
#include <variant>

#include <iostream>

int main(int, char **)
{
    struct callable
    {
        callable()
        {
            std::cout << "callable()" << std::endl;
        }

        ~callable()
        {
            std::cout << "~callable()" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    {
        std::cout << "in_place_type:\n";
        const auto var = std::variant<callable>(std::in_place_type<callable>);
        std::cout << "finished\n";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
        
    {
        std::cout << "by factory:\n";
        const auto var = std::variant<callable>{[] ()-> callable {return {}; }()};
        std::cout << "finished\n";
    }
}
```

I think it does not work in this case because `std::variant(T &&t)` constructor is used with the factory, and it can not use copy elision.

---

I tried to elaborate on [HTNW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5684257/htnw)'s answer (create an onbject from arguments), but get a compiler error:

```
#include <variant>
#include <tuple>

struct to_construct {
  // must NOT exist
  // template<typename F>
  // to_construct(initializer<F>) { std::cout << "Foiled!\n"; }
  // or (more likely)
  // template<typename T>
  // to_construct(T) { std::cout << "Foiled again!\n"; }
  to_construct() = default;
  to_construct(to_construct&&) = delete;
  to_construct(to_construct const&) = delete;
};

#include <iostream>

struct callable
{
    callable(int i)
    {
        std::cout << "callable():" << i << std::endl;
    }

    ~callable()
    {
        std::cout << "~callable()" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct box {
  T x;
  template<typename F>
  box(F f) 
  : x(f())
  {}
};

template<typename F>
struct initializer {
  F init;
  operator auto() {
    return init();
  }
};

template<typename F>
initializer(F) -> initializer<F>;

template <typename ... Types, typename Factory, typename ... Args>
std::variant<box<Types>...> variant_from(Factory &&f, Args &&... args)
{
    return {
        initializer{
            [tupleArgs = std::forward_as_tuple(args...),
            f = std::forward<Factory>(f)](){
                return std::apply(f, tupleArgs);
            }
        }
    };
}


int main() 
{  
  {
      const auto var = 
        std::variant<to_construct>(initializer{
            []() -> to_construct { 
                std::cout << "Success\n";
                return {}; 
                }
            });
  }
   
  {
      const auto var = variant_from<callable>([](int i) { return callable(i);}, 42);
  }
}
```

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'box<T>::box(F) [with F = initializer<variant_from<callable, main()::<lambda(int)>, int>(main()::<lambda(int)>&&, int&&)::<lambda()> >; T = callable]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/variant:283:4:   required from 'constexpr std::__detail::__variant::_Uninitialized<_Type, false>::_Uninitialized(std::in_place_index_t<0>, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {initializer<variant_from<callable, main()::<lambda(int)>, int>(main()::<lambda(int)>&&, int&&)::<lambda()> >}; _Type = box<callable>]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/variant:385:4:   required from 'constexpr std::__detail::__variant::_Variadic_union<_First, _Rest ...>::_Variadic_union(std::in_place_index_t<0>, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {initializer<variant_from<callable, main()::<lambda(int)>, int>(main()::<lambda(int)>&&, int&&)::<lambda()> >}; _First = box<callable>; _Rest = {}]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/variant:460:4:   required from 'constexpr std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_storage<false, _Types ...>::_Variant_storage(std::in_place_index_t<_Np>, _Args&& ...) [with long unsigned int _Np = 0; _Args = {initializer<variant_from<callable, main()::<lambda(int)>, int>(main()::<lambda(int)>&&, int&&)::<lambda()> >}; _Types = {box<callable>}]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/variant:557:20:   required from 'constexpr std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_base<_Types>::_Variant_base(std::in_place_index_t<_Np>, _Args&& ...) [with long unsigned int _Np = 0; _Args = {initializer<variant_from<callable, main()::<lambda(int)>, int>(main()::<lambda(int)>&&, int&&)::<lambda()> >}; _Types = {box<callable>}]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/variant:1448:57:   required from 'constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant(std::in_place_index_t<_Np>, _Args&& ...) [with long unsigned int _Np = 0; _Args = {initializer<variant_from<callable, main()::<lambda(int)>, int>(main()::<lambda(int)>&&, int&&)::<lambda()> >}; _Tp = box<callable>; <template-parameter-2-4> = void; _Types = {box<callable>}]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/variant:1419:27:   required from 'constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant(_Tp&&) [with _Tp = initializer<variant_from<callable, main()::<lambda(int)>, int>(main()::<lambda(int)>&&, int&&)::<lambda()> >; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Tj = box<callable>; <template-parameter-2-5> = void; _Types = {box<callable>}]'
<source>:61:5:   required from 'std::variant<box<Types>...> variant_from(Factory&&, Args&& ...) [with Types = {callable}; Factory = main()::<lambda(int)>; Args = {int}]'
<source>:78:46:   required from here
<source>:36:8: error: no match for call to '(initializer<variant_from<callable, main()::<lambda(int)>, int>(main()::<lambda(int)>&&, int&&)::<lambda()> >) ()'
   36 |   : x(f())
      |       ~^~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In instantiation of 'box<T>::box(F) [with F = initializer<variant_from<callable, main()::<lambda(int)>, int>(main()::<lambda(int)>&&, int&&)::<lambda()> >; T = callable]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/variant:283:4:   required from 'constexpr std::__detail::__variant::_Uninitialized<_Type, false>::_Uninitialized(std::in_place_index_t<0>, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {initializer<variant_from<callable, main()::<lambda(int)>, int>(main()::<lambda(int)>&&, int&&)::<lambda()> >}; _Type = box<callable>]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/variant:385:4:   required from 'constexpr std::__detail::__variant::_Variadic_union<_First, _Rest ...>::_Variadic_union(std::in_place_index_t<0>, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {initializer<variant_from<callable, main()::<lambda(int)>, int>(main()::<lambda(int)>&&, int&&)::<lambda()> >}; _First = box<callable>; _Rest = {}]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/variant:460:4:   required from 'constexpr std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_storage<false, _Types ...>::_Variant_storage(std::in_place_index_t<_Np>, _Args&& ...) [with long unsigned int _Np = 0; _Args = {initializer<variant_from<callable, main()::<lambda(int)>, int>(main()::<lambda(int)>&&, int&&)::<lambda()> >}; _Types = {box<callable>}]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/variant:557:20:   required from 'constexpr std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_base<_Types>::_Variant_base(std::in_place_index_t<_Np>, _Args&& ...) [with long unsigned int _Np = 0; _Args = {initializer<variant_from<callable, main()::<lambda(int)>, int>(main()::<lambda(int)>&&, int&&)::<lambda()> >}; _Types = {box<callable>}]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/variant:1448:57:   required from 'constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant(std::in_place_index_t<_Np>, _Args&& ...) [with long unsigned int _Np = 0; _Args = {initializer<variant_from<callable, main()::<lambda(int)>, int>(main()::<lambda(int)>&&, int&&)::<lambda()> >}; _Tp = box<callable>; <template-parameter-2-4> = void; _Types = {box<callable>}]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/variant:1419:27:   required from 'constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant(_Tp&&) [with _Tp = initializer<variant_from<callable, main()::<lambda(int)>, int>(main()::<lambda(int)>&&, int&&)::<lambda()> >; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Tj = box<callable>; <template-parameter-2-5> = void; _Types = {box<callable>}]'
<source>:61:5:   required from 'std::variant<box<Types>...> variant_from(Factory&&, Args&& ...) [with Types = {callable}; Factory = main()::<lambda(int)>; Args = {int}]'
<source>:78:46:   required from here
<source>:36:8: error: no match for call to '(initializer<variant_from<callable, main()::<lambda(int)>, int>(main()::<lambda(int)>&&, int&&)::<lambda()> >) ()'
   36 |   : x(f())
      |       ~^~
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8MMMEe3jx

Comment: The `T&&` constructor has to bind to an object, so no copy elision.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess. There is no constructor overload for `std::variant` that would take a factory object. I am just not sure if there may be any workarounds. So the answer saying "it is not possible" would be legit

Comment: If you are using `box` you are not supposed to use `initializer` as well as explained in the answer. There is no need to use the init-captures in `variant_from`. Just `[&]` will be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

The factory needs to be wrapped in a type with a conversion to the contained type, and the contained type needs to *not* have a constructor that would take precedence.

```
template<typename F>
struct initializer {
  F init;
  operator auto() {
    return init();
  }
};
template<typename F>
initializer(F) -> initializer<F>;

struct to_construct {
  // must NOT exist
  // template<typename F>
  // to_construct(initializer<F>) { std::cout << "Foiled!\n"; }
  // or (more likely)
  // template<typename T>
  // to_construct(T) { std::cout << "Foiled again!\n"; }
  to_construct() = default;
  to_construct(to_construct&&) = delete;
  to_construct(to_construct const&) = delete;
};

int main() {
  std::variant<to_construct, int> v;
  v.emplace<to_construct>(initializer{[]() -> to_construct { std::cout << "Success\n"; return {}; }});
}
```

The point that the contained type cannot have a constructor matching `initializer` is important: it means you cannot safely do this trick for `variant`s of types that you do not control. If you need to construct some external `T` in a `variant` in this way, instead wrap the `T` in a `box` of your own control, in which case you can just add a constructor from a factory directly anyway.

```
// do NOT do this, because it might fail silently and weirdly
// template<typename T>
// void foo() {
//   std::variant<int, T> v;
//   v.emplace<1>(initializer{[]() -> T { return {}; }});
// }

template<typename T>
struct box {
  T x;
  template<typename F>
  box(F f) : x(f()) { }
};
template<typename T>
void foo() {
  std::variant<int, box<T>> v;
  v.template emplace<1>([]() -> T { return {}; });
}
```

I.e. you can construct an object in a `variant` from a factory without changing the `variant` type *sometimes* (when you control the alternatives), but in general you may need to change some alternatives into `box`s.

---

The issue with your expanded code based on the above is that you try to use `initializer` with `box`. `box` does not need `initializer`. It takes lambdas directly. Further, since the initializing lambda does not have to live past the construction of the `variant`, it should pretty much never capture by value. Also, if you don't want to specify which alternative you want manually every time, you should make `box`'s constructor drop out of overload resolution if it would not work.

```
// it is convention in the C++ standard libraries to not bother forwarding functors
template<typename... Types, typename Factory, typename... Args>
std::variant<box<Types>...> variant_from(Factory f, Args&&... args) {
    return [&]() { return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...); };
}

template<typename T>
struct box {
  T x;
  template<
    typename F,
    typename = std::enable_if_t< // unsure if this is quite the right condition, it's a bit stricter than just "x(f()) would compile"
      std::is_same_v<
        T,
        std::decay_t<decltype(std::declval<F&>()())>>>>
  box(F f) : x(f()) { }
};
```

Comment: So what if I have *no* control on whether the variant's types have or don't have move constructors? Would it help to wrap them inside a non-movable and non-copyable objects within a variant? And what about factories that construct from arguments? Would it suffice to mark a `initializer<T>` constructor `delete`d?

Comment: If someone else is setting the `variant` type *and* you can't ensure the alternative you're constructing lacks constructors matching `initializer`, you're out of luck. Nothing in my code requires move constructors. I don't know what wrapping you're suggesting; the only one you should need is `box<T>`. A `delete`'d `initializer<T>` constructor would also break things. It needs to *not be declared*. It doesn't make sense to have a factory with arguments here. Do you mean a factory that e.g. captures variables and returns objects made from those?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/4d6Px41r4 the second one does not compile. Also, in my case, the user provides a `Factory(args...)`, and I am initializing the variant by providing the actual arguments for the factory

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik `box` is meant to be constructed directly from a lambda. It doesn't need `initializer`. Remove the `initializer` and it compiles. And again, it does not make sense for the initializer to have arguments. You mean you're doing something like `template<typename F> void foo(F f) { int i = 5; std::variant<something>(initializer{[&]() -> something { return f(i, "a", false); }});`. The initializer does not have arguments (empty `()` in lambda), can not have arguments, and does not need arguments.

Comment: *it is convention in the C++ standard libraries to not bother forwarding functors* - what if one's factory is stateful, and is impossible to copy? And is owned by the caller?

Comment: could you also mention in your answer, how can a variant deduce the `box`'s specialization? There are no deduction guides in the code, and `box`'s constructor is a template accepting `F` callable. I see that `T` will be deduced only within a template constructor form `F::operator()`'s return value. Also there is no overload for variant's constructor that accepts "Args...", which I think lambda *is* in this case (construct `box` in-place from callable).

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik For a noncopyable factory, you simply pass `std::ref(f)` instead of `f`. That's why the standard library doesn't bother avoiding copies of functors. You can make `box`'s constructor use SFINAE for the latter issue. We are using the `template<typename T> variant(T&&)` constructor, which is specified to choose the alternative as if by resolving overloads `void a(Alt1), a(Alt2), ...;`